# How do I turn off the browser's form validation?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to turn off the browser's form validation, so that I can leave empty fields. I found that this is with required - false, but where exactly should a set it? I couldn't find the answer. I tried this

```
    $builder->add
(
    'start_date', 
    'date', 
    array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    ), 
    array(
        'required'  => false
    )
);
```

but with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$builder->add
(
    'start_date', 
    'date', 
    array(
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'required'  => false
    )
);
```